# problem with resource leak warning from stream

Tags: java, java-stream, resource-leak

I have the following code causing a `Potential resource leak: '<unssigned Closable value>' may not be closed` warning in static code check:

```
Stream<? extends someClass> stream = someCollection.stream()
    .limit(item -> !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) //
    .limit(more limit criteria) //
    .peek(container) //
    .map(item -> new someClass(r, container.value()));

_publisher = new StreamPublisher<>();
_publisher.subscribe(subscriber);
_publisher.attach(stream);
```

I already tried to wrap the stream into a try-with-resource, but this does not resolve the issue:

```
try (Stream<? extends someClass> stream = someCollection.stream()
    .limit(item -> !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) //
    .limit(more limit criteria) //
    .peek(container) //
    .map(item -> new someClass(r, container.value()))) {

        _publisher = new StreamPublisher<>();
        _publisher.subscribe(subscriber);
        _publisher.attach(stream);
    }
```

Any idea how to get rid of the warning?

Comment: You don’t need to close a Stream created from a Collection. So you may just ignore this false warning. However, `.limit(item -> !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())` doesn’t work at all. `limit` expects a `long` argument.

Comment: The `Stream` is not closed because you are not performing a [terminal operation](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/java-8-stream-terminal-operations-examples).

Answer (score 0):

It may be that it's giving the warning because you're
not short-circuiting the stream, although it does sound quite unlikely.
Perhaps the `_publisher.subscriber()` isn't short circuiting?